# typescript conditional return type based on input parameter not working as expected when testing against extending undefined

Tags: typescript

the return type of `func` next should be `number` if the argument `arg` is given else it's should be `string`, however, testing with `extending undefined` does not work as expected. if I would test `arg` against `extending number` or another normal type it would work as expected.

```js
const func = <T>(arg?:T): T extends undefined?number:string=>{
    if(arg) return 's' as any
    else return 10 as any
}
let ff = func()
ff // string - but should be number
```

how can I test with [typescript conditional typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) if an argument is given or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for such purpose:

```js
type FalsyValues = '' | null | undefined | 0 | false // no NaN

function func(): 's'
function func(arg: FalsyValues): 's'
function func(arg: unknown): 10
function func<T>(arg?: T | undefined): "s" | 10
function func<T,>(arg?: T) {
    if (arg) return 's'
    else return 10
}
let f = func() // 's'
let ff = func(0) // 's'
let fff = func(1) // 10
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgGwM4gGqIK4SVAvFAcgKgB8oA7DBBUqDcgEwgDMBLciB2gBlucSTQA9EIoB7KADk4kgFCzm9AMbBWY8lEXklACgCUALkJICC5avWblOuACcA5kfjI0mbIeOmtKtRu82HI3oAa3IxAHdyDwBGbjNtCz9lAB4AFQA%20APsAfiNU2nomNg4GDwAiJDLaWPifS280gBpMuxy8vSgAb1koXqhWZigsjtsIYAxbDQITHr6IZGhR8cmoGoBfWQQxzTwrbX0oEU9N7eZB-H9uDqPp0y3gTTPd-2jr0RqgA)

**UPDATE**

```js
type FalsyValues = '' | null | undefined | 0 | false // no NaN

type Conditional<T> = T extends FalsyValues ? T extends unknown ? unknown extends T ? never : 's' : never : 10

function func<T extends string | null | undefined | number | boolean | object>(arg?: T): Conditional<T> {
    if (arg) {
        return 's' as Conditional<T>
    }
    else return 10 as Conditional<T>
}
let f = func('') // 's'
let ff = func(0) // 's'
let fff = func(1) // 10
let ffff = func() // 's' | 10
```

The main problem is with function without argument

Since you did not specify the type of argument, I assume it may be anything.
Hence, I have defined `FalseValues` type is case if you provide some argument to the function

**UPDATE**
I have added extra constraints:

```js
type FalsyValues = '' | null | undefined | 0 | false // no NaN

type Conditional<T> = T extends FalsyValues ? 's' : 10

function func<T extends string | null | undefined | number | boolean | object = null>(arg?: T): Conditional<T> {
    if (arg) {
        return 's' as Conditional<T>
    }
    else return 10 as Conditional<T>
}
let f = func('') // 's'
let ff = func(0) // 's'
let fff = func(1) // 10
let ffff = func() // 's'
```

[Playground](http://This%20is%20because%20when%20you%20use%20%60Conditional%3CT%3E%60%20as%20a%20return%20type,%20TS%20still%20don%27t%20know%20the%20type%20of%20%60T%60,%20hence%20%60Conditional%60%20type%20is%20treated%20as%20a%20conditional%20statement%20and%20not%20a%20return%20type%20of%20itself.%20In%20other%20words%20it%20still%20not%20evaluated.)

Comment: Why conditional operator does not work as expected with undefined? Can we solve this with conditional typing? ?

Comment: using your updated example - in my IDE all examples returns 10 [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHlnz.png)

Comment: My bad. Updated

Comment: actually, after rereading your answe - all I really needed it the default `T=null` in `func`. why is that?? [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYB4AqAfFALxT5QQAewEyAzlAK7IQBmKCESUA-FAHJ6AqAC4oARgAMAbgBQctiwDG6RFCUJlBUlARNs2QgApMAJwDmvcfgCU4+MjQYEOAsQDecqFBRsoppa2UF4+PmYQwExmCILCUJiMjqhqrnhE8j4AvpTY9NARUTGSUglJiCkubhlyWXLYkRq6msrGAgK2MlAA9N0l9Y1s-mQtxlKdPX3SA8AaQ80qxhITvf0Ns0PzI4srfUICM3ObC1rG+oa7-UA)

Comment: [see updated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgGwM4gGqIK4SVAvFAOwwQSgB8oMCATCAMwEsCJqAoV0SKAYQHsaGwBv0QAeACoA+PFHFQIAD2AQaOeMjSZsUAPxQA5En1QAXFACMABnZ0qAYyH8otgnYnylK6jjgEQMohJJAAo4ACcAcx0zcQBKMz4BRwIxKSgAb1YoKAY6KFDI2Iys7KgwiGAMMIIDIyg4HETqQWEUhAlJEoBfEohkaHLK6otLesb+ZuTUzp6ECudzGRc7YP19IoB6DZHWOeBnACYl+2DLTe2rXfm6AGZj12Dzc5295wBWe5Xnw312IA)

Comment: but why is that `T=null` required?

Comment: This is because if you dont provide any argument to `func` by the default `T` infers as `unknown` but if you add `=null`, `T` infers as a `null` type

Answer (score 0):

captin-yossarian answer is great and help me get to this answer, but all I really needed was this:

```js
function func<T extends any = undefined>(arg?: T): T extends undefined ? 's' : 10 {
  if (arg) {
    return 's' as any
  }
  else return 10 as any
}

let f1 = func('') // 10
let f2 = func(0) // 10
let f3 = func(1) // 10
let f5 = func() // 's'
```

as he explained in the comments, the default parameter for conditional parameter is `unknown` but what I needed it to be `undefined`. the `T extends any = undefined` is the trick