# How do I get type inference when return type depends on generic type parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

How can I get return type inference for a generic function whose return type depends on the generic type parameter?

Consider the following:

```js
const foo = <Cond extends boolean>(cond: Cond) => {
  return cond ? "a" : "b";
}

type a = ReturnType<typeof foo<true>>; // "a" | "b"
type b = ReturnType<typeof foo<false>>; // "a" | "b"
```

If I add return type information, the types become correct but TypeScript complains:

```js
const foo = <Cond extends boolean>(
  cond: Cond,
): Cond extends true ? "a" : "b" => {
  return cond ? "a" : "b"; // Type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to type 'Cond extends true ? "a" : "b"'.
};

type a = ReturnType<typeof foo<true>>; // "a"
type b = ReturnType<typeof foo<false>>; // "b"
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Typescript how can I set a conditional return type based on a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724605/in-typescript-how-can-i-set-a-conditional-return-type-based-on-a-function-argume), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067742/typescript-conditional-return-type-based-on-input-parameter-not-working-as-expec?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to use type assertion on the return value instead of return type information:

```js
const foo = <Cond extends boolean>(
  cond: Cond,
) => {
  return (cond ? "a" : "b") as Cond extends true ? "a" : "b";
};

type a = ReturnType<typeof foo<true>>; // "a"
type b = ReturnType<typeof foo<false>>; // "b"
```